# Paste bitmap image in Powerpoint, can't resize. Error selection.shaperange: invalid request . nothing appropriate is being selected

Tags: excel, vba, bitmap, resize, powerpoint

```
I'm running vba to copy and paste ranges from Excel to PPT and I just changed the paste type to Bitmap and now I keep getting this error: 

 - selection.shaperange: invalid request . nothing appropriate is being
   selected

on this line of code:

- PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 0

I have Excel 2010 and need to use late binding as you can see from the code below.I have searched far and wide but can't seem to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 

    'variables for referencing PPT
    Dim PPApp As Object
    Dim PPPres As Object
    Dim PPSlide As Object
' And another variable to hold a shape
    Dim PPTShp as Shape
    Dim PresentationFileName As Variant
    Dim SlideCount As Long
    Dim lngSlideHeight      As Long
    Dim lngSlideWidth       As Long


    ' reference existing instance of PowerPoint
    Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

    ' reference active presentation
    ' 1 = PPViewSlide
    Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = 1

    ' Determine height and width of slide
    lngSlideHeight = PPPres.PageSetup.SlideHeight
    lngSlideWidth = PPPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth


        'select the object / table
        Range("H13:K24").Select

        'copy the object / table
        Selection.CopyPicture appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
        'Selection.Copy

        'add a new slide and paste in the table
        '12 = ppLayoutBlank
        If (SheetMap(h) = "Charts") Then
        SlideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
        Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount + 1, 12)
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide PPSlide.SlideIndex
        End If

        'paste and select the table
        '1 = PPpasteBitmap
' It's best NEVER to rely on selection if you can avoid it, so
' instead of this:
        PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=1
' do this picks up the shape rather than the shaperange:
        Set PPTShape = PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(1)(1)
        'Conditional formatting of slide (based on step)
        If (SheetMap(h) = "Charts") Then
' You don't need to go to the slide to work with its shapes.
' Use the shape reference created above instead:

'            PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide PPSlide.SlideIndex
            PPTShp.Left = 0
            PPTShp.Top = 50
            PPTShp.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            PPTShp.ScaleHeight 0.9322, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTop
            PPTShp.ScaleWidth 0.6954, msoTrue, msoScaleFromLeft
            PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 16#
        End If


        'add titles
        '1 = PPAlignLeft
        If (SheetMap(h) = "Charts") Then
            Set osh = PPSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=8, Top:=15, Width:=lngSlideWidth, Height:=10)
            osh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TitleMap(h, 1)
            osh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            osh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
            osh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = True
            osh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Italic = False
            osh.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
            osh.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet = False
       End If

       End If
```

Comment: Hi. You can improve your chances of getting an answer by providing your code in the "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" format - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. (E.g. Currently the attached code does not fail in the described manner when copy-pasted in VB - it fails with an error about "h" not being defined)

Comment: See the edited version.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used Dim Pptshp as Object and copied the rest of the code as you have and it works!